# Perform an action when Gutenberg ServerSideRender Finishes

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to run a javascript code whenever my block's ServerSideRender completes the loading of contents and display them into the editor.

Is there any hook/event available?

Comment: Answers will be more helpful if you add the code you are writing because your statement is confusing.